# Вертикальная прокрутка страницы fullpagescroll.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullpage

Нужно реализовать так
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage)

Но у меня не получается сделать скрол внутри секций. Инициализирую плагин так

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  scrollOverflow: true
});
```

Вот HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
</div>
```

Что еще нужно не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключили все нужные стили/скрипты?
Например, для функции scrollOverflow необходимо подключить вот это:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
```

Источник: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/lang/russian#%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2